# Create a Windows Form from a background Thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm developing a VS Package and I have this problem:

I have a Background-Thread which checks every few seconds for specific changes that have to be done. This includes changing the GUI of VS 2010, which works perfectly fine **without an invoke** for some reason.

Anyway if I try to open a new Form, it opens, but it doesn't show anything, kind of crashes and doesn't respond.
I've already tried `Application.OpenForms[0].invoke( /* delegate to create the form */)`.
This works fine, **but I don't have an open form all the time**.
I've also tried to create a System.Windows.Forms.Timer, **but it doesn't start** in the first place.

**Question:** How can I get the correct GUI thread to invoke my Form?
**or rather:** How can I create a new Form from my background thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Store instance of SynchronizationContext.Current somewhere when your main application starts.
Once set up.
you can try following code in any other thread.

```
 GuiContext.Send(_ => {
                        Form2 frm2=new Form2();
                        frm2.ShowDialog();
                       }, null);
```

Where GuiContext is the stored instance of the SynContext.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I tried `Application.Run(/*create form*/)`, but this blocks unfortunately. I had to modify your answer a little, because I couldn't compile otherwise. My solution is this: `syncContext.Send(delegate(object someState) { /*create form*/  }, null);` and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without any global variables is (sorry for VB.NET - was doing this in VB.NET):

```
 Dim result as Object
 Dim deleg As ThreadStart = Sub() result = DoSomethingHere()
 If Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState <> ApartmentState.STA Then
 Dim t As New Thread(deleg)
     t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) 'Set the thread to STA
     t.Start()
     t.Join() 'Wait for the thread to end
 Else
     deleg.Invoke()
 End If
```